# Getting error with ES6 `array.find`: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code, which is returning the error:

> "cannot read property 'albumCover' of undefined

Based on the code at line 24.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import albumData from './../data/albums';

class Album extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const album = albumData.find( album => {
            return album.slug === this.props.match.params.slug
        });

        this.state = {
            album: album
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section className ="album">
                <section id="album-info">
                    <img id="album-cover-art" src={this.state.album.albumCover} /> <- error
                    <div className="album-details">
                        <h1 id="album-title"></h1>
                        <h2 className="artist"></h2>
                        <div id="release-info"></div>
                    </div>
                </section>
          </section>
        );
    }
}

export default Album
```

My understanding is that this is due to a problem with the context of 'this' not being set correctly, but as far as I can see, this code should execute correctly. Can anyone tell my why I'm getting the error, and how to set the right context for 'this'?

Comment: Did you log your album in render to be sure that this.state.album is set ?

Comment: I suppose this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468837/get-path-params-in-react-router-v4/45469647#45469647 or perhaps this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47221853/react-router-dom-link-change-url-but-does-not-render/47222270#47222270

Comment: after render before return try to console.log(this.state) and verify the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see how [#array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) works, it will **return undefined** if all the elements fails the condition, otherwise return that single element.

As per [MDN DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array
>   that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is
>   returned.

Check this snippet (find will return undefined):

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4,5].find(el => el>5);

console.log('a = ', a);   // will be undefined
```

That's why you are getting the error, when you are trying to access the property of undefined:

> cannot read property 'albumCover' of undefined.

**Solution:**

Use [Short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) concept and put `|| {}`, if `find` returns `undefined`, it will assign the `{}` blank object to album value.

Like this:

```
this.state = {
     album: album || {},
};
```

And use it like this:

```
src={this.state.album.albumCover || ''}
```

Or use `album || {src: ''}`:

```
this.state = {
    album: album || {src: ''}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the fix for this problem could be

```
 <img id="album-cover-art" alt="some-default-image" src={this.state.album ? this.state.album.albumCover : ''} /> <- error
```

Comment: I don't think will will quite solve the OP problem, it will remove the error for sure

Answer (score 0):

Your props area being passed in here as a parameter, so rather than trying to access via `this.props`, just access the parameter directly.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const album = albumData.find( album => {
        return album.slug === props.match.params.slug
    });

    this.state = {
        album: album
    };
}
```

Also then you will want to check to see if you then have an `album` set in the state properly before trying to read from it.