# Cannot render same route with different parameters react router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am implementing a react page with route info/:id. From this page, there are various URLs which are navigated by NavLink.

For example: if current route is **localhost:3000/info/1** and there are links **localhost:3000/info/2** and **localhost:3000/info/3**, clicking on those links will load the page I'm currently on i.e: **localhost:3000/info/1**. While tracking for props changes, url is getting changed briefly but it's again loading the same page. What shall I do to route to same component with different parameters?

Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: Can you share some code please?

Comment: We'd need to see how you set up your routes to help you

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: "While tracking for props changes, url is getting changed briefly but it's again loading the same page" is this intended behavior or are you asking for help fixing this behavior?

Comment: I soved same problem from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47222270/3628295

Answer (score 12):

You should track your page updates in [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle method or [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook.

Class components:

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   if(prevProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id){
     // do something
   }
 }
```

Functional components:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // do something
}, [props.match.params.id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you achieve same via React hooks and functional components:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //do something
}, [props.match.params.id]);
```